# Using Ruby On Rails 2.3, is it possible to accept nested attributes in one form using ActiveResource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, activeresource, nested-attributes

I have a Profile -> Photo relationship on the "server" application. The client application would the ability to upload up to three photos to the server side.

A side note: I am using Paperclip plugin on the serving app.

I have done something like this successfully with a one-to-one relationship but never with a has_many.

Naturally, **ActiveResource** does not have the build method.

How can each Photo be initialized?

```
3.times{@profile.photos.build}
```

will not work

How will this be accomplished in the view also?
I was considering manually coding 3 file_fields naming each one.
e.g.

```
    <%= file_field_tag 'profile[photos_attributes][0][data]' %>
    <%= file_field_tag 'profile[photos_attributes][1][data]' %>
    <%= file_field_tag 'profile[photos_attributes][2][data]' %>
```

would I need a fields_for block for each photo instance?

Long story short, how do I successfully initialize/accept the form data for Profile and its child model, Photo?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `build` method, try this:

```
3.times { @profile.photos << Photo.new }
```

Comment: would this require a fields_for block? If so, how would each distinct field be differentiated? Since the auto-magic field generation won't work here, how would the template know to build 3 file_fields?

Comment: @Martin What you might not realize is that `fields_for` is an _iterator_. If there are three empty photo objects, it will create fields for all three.